# Destroying multiple scenes scrollmagic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, scrollmagic, dom-node

I am using [Scrollmagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) in an angular js app. My app has a sidebar on right with infinite scrolling. There are sections which stick for a particular amount of time then unstick like below

- Section A comes into view and sticks
- Section A remains sticky for few pixels and then unsticks
- Section B appears and sticks after few pixels
- Section B remains sticky for few pixels and then unsticks and so on..

So in effect i create multiple scenes and add it to the scrollMagicController. I am now suspecting memory leaks due to scrollmagic retaining DOM nodes and heap profiler of devtools proves this. I know that there is a destroy method for scene and controller which needs to be called to clear things up but i can't figure out how to destroy multiple nodes. Below is what i have tried

```
var scrollMagicCtrl = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

//create scene dynamically whenever stickyContainerInView event fires
scope.$on('stickyContainerInView', function(event, inViewElement) {    
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: someElement, //Selector or DOM object that defines the start of the scene
            triggerHook: 'onLeave', //sets the position of trigger hook w.r.t viewport
            duration: someDuration, //The duration(in pixels) for which the element will remain sticky
            offset: -60 //Offset Value for the Trigger hook position
        })
        .setPin(someContainer)
        .addTo(scrollMagicCtrl);
});

//clean up things on angular's destroy method
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {    
    scrollMagicCtrl.destroy();
    scrollMagicCtrl = null;
});
```

I guess i just need to call the controller's destroy method and it should automatically destroy all the scenes added to it but unfortunately it doesn't work that way.

Screenshot of heap profiler detached DOM node tree
[image]

Any help on how should i clear up things ?

Comment: Does the scope belongs to the sidebar? And is the sidebar destroyed ever? Any way, it is better to handle scene cleanup per element, instead of scope $destroy events. Once the element is destroyed, the relevant scene is destroyed too, e.g. someElement.on('$destroy', () => { someScene.destroy() }). It is not clear what is the context for this code, it is hard to suggest anything more specific.

Comment: I currently have two views A & B. Sidebar is a child in A. The scope in the code above doesn't belong to sidebar but is a parent scope of it. The scene that controls the sticky behavior of sections in sidebar is created in scope of A.

The element don't get destroyed until i change view from A to B hence i can't do anything on destroy event of element itself. Are you really sure that once the element gets destroyed the relevant scene gets destroyed too ? Infact the as the scene is not being cleaned up the element stays as detached node in js heap.

Comment: And yes the sidebar gets destroyed when i move from view A to view B.

Comment: So the point is that in your case scope $destroy listener may not even been called. Because it belongs to parent which is never destroyed. And you should revise the code to make scene/controller destroy() called (controller destroy calls scene destroy internally, so both should work). Element $destroy event is bound to Angular jqLite implementation (e.g. when the element is removed by ng-repeat or with el.remove() ), not to actual element existence. It is there exactly to clean up and avoid DOM-related leaks.

Comment: As i move from A to B scope of A gets destroyed.The code above is in A's scope so my scope.$destroy is getting called correctly, it is not a problem. Also i am calling scrollmagic controller destroy event in scope.$destroy and i can see the logs are fine but still dom nodes aren't getting cleared.